# Php preg_match issue

Tags: php

With following php preg_match i'm trying to show a error message if someone input any value except a-z or  0-9 in a textarea form. Just only user can type string and numerice value. Not , < ? >any php, javascript tag etc.

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/ ", $wall) != 1)
$err[] = "Wrong value";
```

So, if  i put **php tag** to the begning of the form then it's show error message but if i put "Some text then type **php tag** and  another value" then it's doesn't show any error message.

Sorry my bad english.:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just check whether there is any character you don't want.

```
if(preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ ", $wall)) {
  $err[] = "Wrong value";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/ ", $wall) ) {
    $err[] = "Wrong value";
}
```

You have to anchor the beginning and end otherwise they can type `a#$@#$@#$#`.

Also, no need for the `!= 1` at the end.  It's more readable without it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've set the expression to check alphanumeric characters at the beginning of string using `^`

if you change it to this, this will check if it has a < or > anywhere in the string:

```
if(preg_match("/[<|>]+/ ", $wall))
$err[] = "Wrong value";
```

Comment: @tehluz it's not working.. it's successfully inserted. if write -- sometext then php tag then sometext.

Comment: had to change the regex as well.